# origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5174' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cors

```
**frontend main.jsx**

import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./styles/app.scss";
import { createContext } from "react";

export const server = "https://mern-todoapp-bc0e.onrender.com/api/v1" || " http://localhost:3000/api/v1";

export const Context = createContext({ isAuthenticated: false });

const AppWrapper = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});



  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        setIsAuthenticated,
        loading,
        setLoading,
        user,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppWrapper />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


**backend app.js**

import express from "express";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.js";
import taskRouter from "./routes/task.js";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { errorMiddleware } from "./middlewares/error.js";
import cors from "cors";

export const app = express();

config({
  path: "./data/config.env",
});

// Using Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://127.0.0.1:5174" || "http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// Using routes
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/task", taskRouter);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Nice working");
});

// Using Error Middleware
app.use(errorMiddleware);
```

I have deployed my api "https://mern-todoapp-bc0e.onrender.com/api/v1" on "render.com" website and my api is working fine and I have also added frontend url in my environment variable section that is "http://localhost:5174".

But when I am trying to access from frontend, I am unable to logged in to my site it is saying cors policy error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyyIk.png)

---------Tried this worked but got another error-------

I have tried to const server="http://localhost:3000/api/v1" only then it is working and I am unable to logged in but after this a new error arises when I add a task (title, description) that error is->>>
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TstRl.png)

POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/task/new 404 (Not Found)

But this "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/task/new"  api is perfectly working in postman but on my site giving above error. I am perfectly set all the routes and even sending the post data(title, description) from frontend correctly still giving same error.

Comment: this needs to enable cors - https://mern-todoapp-bc0e.onrender.com/api/v1/users/new - nothing on your frontend

Comment: The `origin` property doesn't look right.

Comment: If you dont have a control on api side, you can create your own BFF (backend for frontend) to call the webservice endpoint
frontend>BFF>onrender.com

Answer (score 1):

**This cors config should work:**

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://127.0.0.1:5174"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

The error message is telling you that this is your origin.

**If you want to understand further:**

In an http request, there are two entities involved: the client and the server.  The client is the *origin* of the request, and it sends the request to a particular location (or path) on the server.  For example, the addresses might be:

- `http://127.0.0.1:5174` client (origin)
- `http://localhost:3000` server*

In your backend code, the list you provide in the `origin` property of the cors options tells the Express server "allow requests from these origins".

You had `http://127.0.0.1:5174/api/v1` as your origin and then commented it out, presumably because it didn't work. This is because the path (`/api/v1`) refers to a location on the server.  The request looks like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:5174` ==> `http://localhost:3000/api/v1`

The address `http://127.0.0.1:5174/api/v1` doesn't make any sense.  The path is a location on the server, not on the client, so it shouldn't ever be added to the client url.

*Im using the localhost address for simplicity in the explanation, and this *is* the address of your development server, but for your hosted server the address is of course `https://mern-todoapp-bc0e.onrender.com`

Comment: Hey user name: @Datguy your I have done what you said but its giving another error although code seems to be perfect can you have look on my code I have updated

Comment: @PankajGupta can you give more information?  Your screenshot does not show the full error message or the url you are trying to reach.  I would try setting the server url as "http://localhost:3000" in your frontend, and try to make a request to "/" to start - to see if it can reach the server at all.  If it can, and it just fails on those other routes, then there is something else going on.

Comment: @PankajGupta I would also suggest taking a look at this, the way you are using || in some places does not make sense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR